# How to get CSS as a string from a versioned Webpack Encore build, to use it in an email?

Tags: symfony, twig, webpack-encore

I render emails using Twig.

To import CSS directly into the email, I did the following:

```
<style>
    {{ source('@public/build/email.css') }}
</style>
```

This works well in dev environment, but does not in production, where assets are versioned (e.g. `email.dfase343.css`).

Is it possible to only disable versioning for this single file?

My `webpack.config.js` ist pretty basic:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

    Encore
        .setOutputPath('public/build/')
        .setPublicPath('/build')
        .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
        .addEntry('email', './assets/js/email.js')
        .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
        .enableBuildNotifications()
        .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

        .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction()) // --> only for app.js

        .enableSassLoader()
    ;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

### Update: My Solution

I wrote a simple Twig function to get around this issue:

```
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{

    private $assetsManager;

    public function __construct(\Symfony\Component\Asset\Packages $assetsManager)
    {
        $this->assetsManager = $assetsManager;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new TwigFunction('asset_embed', array($this, 'assetEmbed')),
        );
    }

    public function assetEmbed($uri, $package = null)
    {
        $file = __DIR__.'/../../public'.$this->assetsManager->getUrl($uri, $package);

        if (is_file($file)) {
            return file_get_contents($file);
        }

        throw new \Twig_Error('File "'.$file.'" not found.');
    }

}
```

#### Usage

```
<style>
    {{ asset_embed('build/email.css') }}
</style>
```

Comment: In your webpack config you are talking about JS files ("only for app.js"), but your problem is about css versioning right? Do you have an entry for css?

Comment: Well, I'm actually not sure how webpack exactly works, but I followed symfony's tutorials. My `email.js` file has this in it: `import '../css/email.scss';`

Comment: In fact I don't understand your problem, why versioning impacts your email template?

Comment: `{{ source('@public/build/email.css') }}` is a Twig function which loads the file's contents into the current template. Since I want to use SCSS in my email template, I need to configure a build process. `source`, other than `asset`, doesn't use the manifest.json file to transform the clean path into a versioned path. So Twig thinks, the file can be found at `build/email.css`, when in fact it is located at `build/email.sdf312321.css`

Comment: I think you need to use asset() instead of source() {{ asset('build/email.css') }} https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#configuring-encore-webpack

Comment: Sure, but you cannot do this with emails. An email needs embedded CSS to work properly. I already thought about creating a custom function like `asset_embed`, but I hoped I can achieve this out of the box, without creating some custom core functionality.

Comment: The maintainer of the webpack encore bundle covers this in a course about the mailer: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/mailer/encore-inline_css

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't answer the question in your title, it will let you get the CSS from the webpack generated file(s) to include in your email.

Webpack Encore creates a file in your build folder called "entrypoints.js". You'll want to get and parse that file using `$decodedFile = json_decode(file_get_contents('your/build/folder/entrypoints.json'));`.

You can then traverse the contents of that file as an object. The file path you want will be at something like `$decodedFile->entrypoints->email->css`, which will give you an array of the CSS files for that entry (there can be more than one file, for example if you have the `.splitEntryChunks()` method in your webpack.config.js file.

After you've got that, you'll want to do `file_get_contents($yourCssFile)` for each file in that array to get the CSS from each file. Bear in mind though that the paths in that file are the web-accessible paths, not the local paths, so you might need to manipulate them.

Of course you can only do all that in PHP, so you'll need to create a Twig extension to allow you to use it in your template.

I'm surprised there isn't a better way to do that in Symfony - I'd love to know of one if there is.

Full code (To be used in a Twig extension method https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html, or just pass `$css` into your template):

```php
$files = json_decode(file_get_contents('your/build/folder/entrypoints.json'))
    ->entrypoints
    ->email
    ->css
;

$css = '';

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $css .= file_get_contents('your/build/folder/') . basename($file));
}
```

Comment: Thank you!. Luckily, I found a very similar workaround a few days after posting this question, added to my question.

Comment: Cool, yeah I figured you'd probably sorted it by now :) Hopefully the answer will help someone else

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a good solution but you could try to add the [ignore-loader plugin](https://github.com/cherrry/ignore-loader) and match files to ignore them, e.g. in `webpack.config.js` ignore all .css files

```
module.exports = {
  // ... other configurations ...
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'ignore-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can disable versioning for certain css file (email.css) using [Encore multiple config](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/advanced-config.html#defining-multiple-webpack-configurations)

Something like that in your `webpack.config.js`:

```
Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/email')
    .setPublicPath('/build/email')
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .disableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSassLoader()
    .addStyleEntry('emails', './assets/css/email.scss')
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
;
```

then `webpack_encore.yaml`

```
webpack_encore:
    output_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build'
    builds:
        frontend: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build'
        emails: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/email'
```

and finally your email template:

```
    <style>
        {{ source('@public/build/email.css') }}
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This topic is old but I was facing to the same question, and I did it in an other way. So this is just another solution.

I would like to use my SCSS variables and others sytles in my emails template, by using inline style as described in the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#using-external-css-files).

So in `webpack.config.ts`, add a new entry

```js
Encore
    ...
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
    .addEntry('email', './assets/styles/email/email.scss')
```

In `email.sccs`, write awesome CSS:

```
@import "my-variables";
// do what you want
html {
  background: pink !important;
  color: green !important;
  font-size: 50rem !important;
}
```

In `config/packages/twig.yaml`, add a new path for `source` function in twig:

```yaml
twig:
    #...
    paths:
        #...
        '%kernel.project_dir%/public': 'asset' # we need an absolute path for 'source' function
```

Finally, there is a function called `encore_entry_css_files` which returns an array of css compiled files, as described in [the webpack-encore-bundle package](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/webpack-encore-bundle).

So in the base email template (`templates/emails/base.html.twig` or whatever):

```
<body>

{% apply inline_css(source('@asset/' ~ encore_entry_css_files('email')|first)) %}

    {% block header %}{% endblock %}

    {% block body %}{% endblock %}

{% endapply %}
</body>
```

And it's done. It's work in dev, and prod (eg: `email.dfase343.css`)

### Edit

If you have several mails to send in the same instance (in a `foreach` for example), Symfony will throw an error like *Unable to find template "@asset/" blablabla*. This is because `encore_entry_css_files` removes files from the result array when it's diplay once.

To fix that, you can add a new twig extention like:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Asset\EntrypointLookupCollectionInterface;
use Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Asset\EntrypointLookupInterface;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class EncoreEntryExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    private EntrypointLookupCollectionInterface $entrypointLookupCollection;

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('encore_entry_css_files_and_reset', [$this, 'getWebpackCssFilesAndReset']),
        ];
    }

    public function __construct(EntrypointLookupCollectionInterface $entrypointLookupCollection)
    {
        $this->entrypointLookupCollection = $entrypointLookupCollection;
    }

    // almost the same as encore_entry_css_files (eg: Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Twig\EntryFilesTwigExtension::getWebpackCssFiles)
    public function getWebpackCssFilesAndReset(string $entryName, string $entrypointName = '_default'): array
    {
        $entrypointLookup = $this->getEntrypointLookup($entrypointName);
        $css = $entrypointLookup->getCssFiles($entryName);
        $entrypointLookup->reset(); // reset is important to rebuild service !
        return $css;
    }

    private function getEntrypointLookup(string $entrypointName): EntrypointLookupInterface
    {
        return $this->entrypointLookupCollection->getEntrypointLookup($entrypointName);
    }
}
```

In `service.yaml`, you need to add:

```yaml
App\Twig\EncoreEntryExtension:
        arguments:
            $entrypointLookupCollection: '@webpack_encore.entrypoint_lookup_collection'
```

Finaly to use in `twig` template

```
{% apply inky_to_html|inline_css(source('@asset/' ~ encore_entry_css_files_and_reset('email')|first)) %}
```